# Annotations don't appear when setting MainViewController as delegate of MKMapView

Tags: ios, delegates, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a funky problem I'm dealing with… i have a very basic mkmapview that i dragged into the mainviewcontrollers view. I have very basic annotations that i am showing on the map. When I make the mainviewcontroller the delegate (in IB or code) of the mapview, the annotations stop showing up. If i don't make this connection, the annotations appear as expected… any ideas?

```
#import "GDFlipsideViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface GDMainViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *bottomToolbar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *theMap;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKLocalSearchResponse *results;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKLocalSearchRequest *request;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKLocalSearch *search;

- (IBAction)locateHelp:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@end
...

@implementation GDMainViewController
...
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";
    GDHelpAnnotationView *annotationView = (GDHelpAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil){
        annotationView = [[GDHelpAnnotationView alloc]init];

    }

    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}

...

- (IBAction)locateHelp:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    [self searchForHelp];
}

..

- (void)searchForHelp {
    // drop pins for emergency destination
    [self searchForFireStations];
    [self searchForPoliceStations];
    [self searchForHospitals];

}

...

- (void)searchForFireStations {
    //Fire stations
    [_request setNaturalLanguageQuery:@"fire station"];
    [_request setRegion:[_theMap region]];
    _search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc]initWithRequest:_request];

    [_search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if ([response.mapItems count] == 0) {
            if ([response.mapItems count] == 0) {
                //will handle later
                return;
            }
        }

        [response.mapItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MKMapItem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            GDHelpAnnotation  *annotation = [[GDHelpAnnotation alloc] initWithPlacemark:item.placemark];
            annotation.title = item.name;
            annotation.subtitle = [item name];

            [_theMap addAnnotation:annotation]; // This gets called but doesnt show annotations when self is _theMap's delegate
        }];



    }];
}
```

Comment: It's probably something frustratingly simple. Have you set up a breakpoint in your `viewForAnnotation` to confirm that it's getting called? Have you logged your mapView's `annotations` array to make sure they got added properly? Etc. It would be good to confirm whether the problem is in adding annotations, linkage of your `delegate`, or the details of `GDHelpAnnotationView`. We need your help narrowing down the issue.

Comment: (As an aside and unrelated, your creation of new `GDHelpAnnotationView` isn't setting the reuse identifier. I assume you're doing that inside your implementation of that class, but it would be good to make it a parameter like it is for the [initializer for the `MKAnnotationView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207-CH1-SW5).)

Comment: But, going back to your original question, if your annotations are showing up if you don't set a delegate, but fail to if you don't, that screams that there's probably a problem in `viewForAnnotation` or, more likely, in `GDHelpAnnotationView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `viewForAnnotation` is being called when you set your delegate, but the pins aren't appearing, the fault probably lies with `GDHelpAnnotationView`. You could test this by replacing your `viewForAnnotation` with this even more basic one that uses a regular old MKPinAnnotationView instead.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
    } else {            
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: Yep that was the problem... now to figure out what I did wrong in my MKAnnotation subclass.